# SQL syntax error with foreign key when I also have primary key

Tags: sql, database, mariadb, xampp, foreign-keys

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'REFERENCES users(id)
)' at line 8

when I try to execute my SQL statement I get the above error.

```
CREATE TABLE projects(
    projectId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR(250),
    others INT NOT NULL,
    notes TEXT,
    userId INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_userId FOREIGN KEY userId REFERENCES users(id)
);
```

I believe the issue could have something to do with the primary key as below is a working SQL statement I wrote that also has a foreign key but no primary key

```
CREATE TABLE about(
    pfp longblob,
    bio VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT " ",
    friends INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    followers INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    id INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_id FOREIGN KEY id REFERENCES users(id)
);
```

Comment: your "working SQL" gets the same error as projects

Comment: Clearly when pinned down this will be a faq. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Comment: verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use parentheses. Here's [a link](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/foreign-keys/#syntax).

```
CONSTRAINT fk_userId FOREIGN KEY (userId) REFERENCES users (id)
```

Comment: a better link is just the documentation: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/foreign-keys/#syntax   Note that the syntax has an optional name for the constraint, followed by the columns to constrain *in parentheses*

Comment: Thanks, link changed.

Answer (score 0):

Mariadb enforces that every auto_increment must be also primary key or unique constraint

As you can see in the second query.

```
CREATE tABLe users (id BIGINT NOt NULL auto_increment primary key)
```

```
CREATE TABLE projects(
    projectId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR(250),
    others INT NOT NULL,
    notes TEXT,
    userId BIGINT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_userId FOREIGN KEY (userId) REFERENCES users(id)

);
```

```
CREATE TABLE about(
    pfp longblob,
    bio VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT " ",
    friends INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    followers INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_id FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES users(id)
);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2HRT-7RU)

Comment: You silently fixed the actual problem producing the error in your fiddle (missing parens).  Also, auto increment just needs to be indexed, not a primary key or even a unique key.